# a href slider(like image slider, but with links)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want do navigate trough my navigation with arrows. forwoard and backwoards and go back to the first at the last link and to the last at the first. sounds like an image slider with links. I do not know, how to explain it better.

How can I navigate trough links in jquery/ajax?

Here is my code:

```
<?php

require_once    '../include/config.inc.php';

if( isset( $_GET['site'] ) ){

    $site = $_GET['site'];

}else{

        $site = 'Home';
}


?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title><?= $site ?> | <?= $seiten_name ?></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Iceland' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
</head>

<body>
<!-- Start Main content -->
<div id="main">

<!-- Start Background Preloader -->
    <div class="background_pre">
    <!-- Start Preloader -->
        <div class="preloader"></div>
    <!-- End Preloader -->
    </div>
<!-- End Background Preloader -->

    <?php

        ////////////////
        // Navigation //
        ////////////////

        switch ( $site ) {

            case 'Info':
                include('info.php');
                break;

            case 'Projects':
                include('projects.php');
                break;

            case 'Contact':
                include('contact.php');
                break;

        }

    ?>

    <!-- Start Navigation -->
    <nav>
        <?php require('../include/navi.inc.php');?>
    </nav>
</div>
<!-- End Main content -->

<!-- Start Script -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/navi.js"></script>
<!-- End Script -->
</body>
</html>
```

Navigation:

```
<ol>
    <li id="backward"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-backward fa-2x"></i></a></li>
    <li><a class="selected" href="Home"><i class="fa fa-home fa-2x"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="Info"><i class="fa fa-user fa-2x"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="Projects"><i class="fa fa-code fa-2x"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="Contact"><i class="fa fa-comments fa-2x"></i></a></li>
    <li id="forward"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-forward fa-2x"></i></a></li>
</ol>
```

Here is a jsfiddel:
https://jsfiddle.net/nuzggoxo/3/

I want to change the page with the arows!!

Hope, you will understand my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Navigation:

```
<ol class="navigation">
    <li id="backward"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-backward fa-2x"></i></a></li>
    <li><a <?=($site == 'Home') ? 'class="selected"' : ''?> href="Home"><i class="fa fa-home fa-2x"></i></a></li>
    <li><a <?=($site == 'Info') ? 'class="selected"' : ''?> href="Info"><i class="fa fa-user fa-2x"></i></a></li>
    <li><a <?=($site == 'Projects') ? 'class="selected"' : ''?> href="Projects"><i class="fa fa-code fa-2x"></i></a></li>
    <li><a <?=($site == 'Contact') ? 'class="selected"' : ''?> href="Contact"><i class="fa fa-comments fa-2x"></i></a></li>
    <li id="forward"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-forward fa-2x"></i></a></li>
</ol>
```

Javascript:

```
var nav = $('.navigation');
$('#forward').click(function(e) {
    var nextItem = nav.find('.selected').parent().next().find('a');
    if(nextItem.length > 0) {
        window.location.href = nextItem.attr('href');
    }
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
$('#backward').click(function(e) {
    var prevItem = nav.find('.selected').parent().prev().find('a');
    if(prevItem.length > 0) {
        window.location.href = prevItem.attr('href');
    }
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: the "click" function is not working, i don't know why. I will get if i click only for example "localhost/projectname/home#", if i click. and no error in the console.

Comment: Do you have any other javascript / jquery on your site?

Comment: I thought perhaps you had some errors, try to add console(nav); on the second line of my example. What does it show you in console

Comment: [ol.navigation, prevObject: m.fn.init[1], context: document, selector: ".navigation"]0: ol.navigationcontext: documentlength: 1prevObject: m.fn.init[1]selector: ".navigation"__proto__: m[0]

Comment: No, it doesn't go. I did a breakpoint in the browser, when I click on the function and got this result: "e = m.Event {originalEvent: MouseEvent, type: "click", timeStamp: 1448650660284, jQuery1113041367492405697703: true, toElement: i.fa.fa-forward.fa-2x…}" is he maby trying to do something with the <i> and not the <a>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96380/discussion-between-xeli-and-c00l).

Answer (score 0):

I dont know php but what you want is that the next/previous arrows iterate with an array of urls. Something like:

```
var url_array={"index.html","otherpage.html","anotherpage.html"};
array_position=0;
OnNextClick()
{
array_position++;
window.location.href=url_array[array_position];
}

OnPreviousClick()
{
array_position--;
window.location.href=url_array[array_position];
}
```

Comment: I was thinking the same way, but I am not really into javascript. How would the array look like with the url's? In php is it maby header location? I am not sure

Comment: You don't need php for this unless you are grabbing the url's from a DataSource (file, database).
Jquery will make the client avoid a round trip to the server that is unnecessary in this case

Comment: Will it go to the beginning, if I reach the end of the array?